# Visual Studio 2013 Designer and Simulator do not reflect Xaml changes

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, simulator

On my Windows 8.1 Ultimate (Evaluation Copy) I'm trying to start a simple `Hub` Layered Application starting from built-in template.

After some changes (removed one section, changed titles) I've started Windows `Simulator`, but only layout changes are correctly reflected while labels are not updated.

This seems to affect `Local Machine` Debug and `Designer` too. Changing a label works since I come back from simulation, in fact while in `XAML` code I found the right text the designer shows the good old "Lorem Ipsum" sample text.

Is it a standard behaviour? Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Did you do a rebuild? I have noticed this in the past. Sometimes XAML changes wont take effect until you rebuild. Also restarting VS can help.

Comment: Sure, cleaned up twice, build, rebuild, build in Blend and so on...

Comment: Make sure you arent using a design time data source, usually designated with the "d:" namespace. Design time data is only visible in the blend and VS designers. It is there to help you understand how content might look.

Comment: No design time markups.